# Is there a way to create indices within groups of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I am trying to create an index (i.e. a column thats up from 0-n) for different group levels of a factor variable, all within one column.  Specifically, here is a minimal working example, for data frame D:

```
ID  Index
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   2
3   1
3   2
3   3
```

I currently have column 1, and would like to get column 2.  I have struggled way more than I would like with this problem.  I have tried several things, but the following seems like it should have worked:

```
dlply(D, .(ID), function(D){D$index = seq.int(nrow(D$ID))})
```

Comment: Try to `group_by` and then `data.table::rleid` to create the new column. You can use `data.table::rleid` inside `mutate`.

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Index = row_number())`

Comment: @Tung Thank you, this solution worked!  If you add a post below I will mark it as the correct one.  Andrew I did not try your solution, but thank you.

Comment: No worries, as long as your problem is solved!

Comment: @user3859248: no worry. Glad it solved your problem. You can post the answer yourself to help future readers if you want to

Answer (score 4):

The answer Tung provided in the comments of the original question worked for me.  Providing it below for completeness:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Index = row_number())
```